# TAB BAR CONTROLLER

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbar

I have a tab bar controller with 2 view controller. When the application is launched everything works and texts are being shown in the the tab bar but when I select the second view controller(settings) text disappear (image remain shown).
any idea? thanks

[image]

[image]

the label "settings" disappeared.

[image]

Comment: text in the sense the data in the textfields are something else?

Comment: Are you implementing any of the `UITabBarController` methods? And are you implementing the *settings* view controller's `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidAppear:` methods?

Comment: none of the that methods are implemented. It worked before with 5 bar item (this should be a lite version) but now with only 2 bar items it doesn't work.

Comment: @Deepak sorry man, you're right.... in viewDidLoad method I forgot to cancel something that I don't need in this version. Can you please post your answer so I can vote and accept it. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Reposting comment as answer on OP's request.*

Are you implementing any of the UITabBarController methods? And are you implementing the settings view controller's viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear: and viewDidAppear: methods? Guess is that it is being reset in those methods.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're declaring them properly like this:

```
nav.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Home" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"] tag:0];
tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Second" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"] tag:1];
```

If you try declaring the title after initWIthImage you can lose the titles sometimes

I've done it for 5 tab items like above (shortened code obv) and they all work perfectly

EDIT:
You added the the Nib file layout after i posted, I do everything programmatically

Comment: Nps, programmatically gives me more control over the way everything works, I tend to forget to set things in the NIB :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are adding the images and other elements to the AppDelegate's window instead of adding them to the view in "Settings view controller"? Please give some feedback so we can help you better.

Comment: no, i'm sure it's in the setting view controller...I'll post another pic. thanks for your help.